# Is the document snapshot from Expressive Querying auto updated in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Expressive Querying is a big differences with Firestore and Realtime Database. If I use `addSnapshotListener` to a document. I know the snapshot of document will be auto updated at any changing from cloud.

But how about the snapshot from Expressive Querying? I didn't find the detail from the Firestore website.

For example, first for the `Document`.

If I have used `get` function to query a document `posts/{postId}` and get the snapshot of this document. But I didn't `addSnapshotListener` for this document. So will the snapshot be auto updated on the background at data changing from cloud?

Second, for the `Collection`

If I have `getDocuments` of a collection `comments`. And didn't `addSnapshotListener` too. Will the collection at local be auto updated when somebody add a new comment?

I know Firestore is still on the beta version. But I like the easier querying design. I prepare to use Firestore in my next project. So I want to know more behaviors of Firestore. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The on-disk cache of Cloud Firestore functions as a cache. It keeps data that your app has listened to, so that the same data can be returned from disk to future listeners (in case there is no network connection).

Cloud Firestore does not optimistically update the disk cache. The data in the disk cache is only updated when you `get()` the data or attach a listener.